# mongorestore returning less documents with no erro

Tags: mongodb

I am running a mongodump followed by a mongorestore and in 2 out of 12 collections the numbers of documents restored are way less than the number of documents on the backup. The thing is there are no errors.

Bellow is the output fot the 2 collections on the dump

> 2020-01-22T10:16:26.961-0300 done dumping montele.usuario (960
>   documents)
>
> 2020-01-22T10:29:35.268-0300 done dumping montele.negocio (86851
>   documents)

And now the output for the restore

> 2020-01-22T10:35:21.121-0300  finished restoring montele.usuario (31 documents, 0 failures)
>   2020-01-22T10:37:29.974-0300  finished restoring montele.negocio (26120 documents, 0 failures)

Interesting enough .... if I run the mongorestore again without dropping the db this happens:

> 2020-01-22T11:30:41.914-0300  finished restoring montele.negocio (0 documents, 86851 failures)

With the failure code being:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: montele.negocio index: *id* dup
>   key:

After looking for a solution and having no success, I hope someone can shine a light and point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What MongoDB version are you using? Are you restoring the dump into an empty collection or does it already have data in it?

From mongoDB documentation:

> mongorestore can create a new database or add data to an existing
>   database. However, mongorestore performs inserts only and does not
>   perform updates. That is, if restoring documents to an existing
>   database and collection and existing documents have the same value _id
>   field as the to-be-restored documents, mongorestore will not overwrite
>   those documents.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

Comment: Version 4.2.2

A have done both.

1st I did a couple of times on an empty database. All those times even knowing there were 86851 documents in the montele.negocio collection, it restore only 26120 documents with 0 failures. 

After that I tried to run it over a existing DB to see if the remaining data would be added. But now it shows 0 documents and 86851 failures for duplicate keys.

And that is my problem ....

When I run my app code locally and try to use the data it is not there.